# Limit of x^(infinity/infinity)

Tags: limits

Consider the limit
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{x^n}=x
$$ for any real positive $x$, but I will proceed in a different way:
$$
\begin{split}
&\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{e^{\ln(x^n)}}=x\\
&\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{(1+n\ln(x)/n)^n}=x\\
&1+\ln(x)=x
\end{split}
$$
which is obviously wrong, but why? What is the restriction I ignored when evaluating the expression?

Comment: How do you go from $e^{\ln(x^n)}$ to $(1 + n \ln(x) / n)^n$?

Comment: And $e = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{e^n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\left(1+\frac n n\right)^n} = 2$.

Comment: @BenSteffan The definition of $e^x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to combine the inner limit with the outer limit in
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{(1+n\log(x)/m)^m}=x
$$
Note that if you switch the order of the limits, you get
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{(1+n\log(x)/m)^m}=1
$$